# I'm trying to understand how to use special characters in grep and wc

Tags: linux, bash, grep, wc

Can you explain in detail what happened here on this command?

```
grep -nw '^root' /etc/passwd
```

What is the use of **^** and **'**? Please give me examples and be detailed cuz all I'm hearing is that it's the beginning of the line. I don't understand what each of those special characters means.

How would I go about using **wc**, **grep** and **^** to find out the number of non-root processes running on my system?

Comment: Have you looked at the manual page for `grep`? It's explained there. Once you understand that, look at the manual page for `wc`. Then you can probably answer your last question yourself.

Comment: These mysterious thing inside the quotes is a `regular expression`. Information can be found e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075

Comment: Check the man page if in doubt. It's made for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -nw '^root' /etc/passwd
```

It reads the /etc/passwd file line-by-line and filters out all those lines that `^`*=begin with* the `-w`*=complete word* "root". So, for example the line

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

To see all processes on a system, you could use `ps aux`. and it will show lines like this

```
root 22866  0.0 [...] 0:00 [kworker/1:0]
```

As you can see, the lines start with a username. If you pipe the `ps aux` output through `grep`, you can use the same RegEx from above, to filter out all lines that *do not* start with "root".

Use `-v` to invert pattern matching, so that `grep -vw '^root'` finds all lines that *don't* begin with a complete word "root".

```
ps aux | grep -vw '^root' | wc -l
```

Finally, `wc -l` counts the number of lines it receives. So that is the number of all lines from `ps aux` that do not begin with "root".